# Changing size of User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, user-controls, office-addins

I'm having a problem with determining which element is responsible for a **size misalignment**. Here is a picture to illustrate it: [click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPERR.jpg)

The light grey area is the element size which I am trying to change, but cannot. The overall area is a User Control, the area inside the Tab is a WPF (as an element Host). I've tried changing both, but with no effect on the grey area (the other tabs are also affected by this). **Here is the code for the hosted element (WPF)**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SlideAnalyzer.DisplayAnalysis"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SlideAnalyzer"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="150.8" d:DesignWidth="201.2">


<Grid Name="displayGrid" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="160" Margin="10,0,31.6,9.4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,0.94">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander x:Name="expander" Grid.Row="0"  Header="Titel zu lang" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Background="Red" Margin="-10,-56,0,0">

        <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Margin="5"><Run Text="This is some text content."/></TextBlock>

        </Grid>

    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

The host itself is a normal User Control. I cannot seem to get the right size of the hosted element so that the preview really reflects reality (because when I run the Add-In, the size of the WPF differs)

I tried changing the Properties of the UserControl and I found that **AutoSize** has a big impact when True (by default False)
 Thanks!

Comment: If you don't post your code, we will share your problem in determing which element is responsible for that.

Comment: thanks for tip. I just added the code and some clarifications.